# sincos implementation

Tags: numerical-methods

Many computational libraries contain a routine called [sincos](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sincos.3.html) that allows one to compute sin and cos simultaneously. The existence of this routine suggests that calling this routine is more efficient than making a call to sin followed by a call to cos.

I am interested in knowing how sincos is (or can be) implemented to make it more efficient than making two calls.

Comment: So, interestingly, in the glibc source code, it is actually just two separate calls that are made see [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sincos.c#L42).

Comment: The cephes library has a both a [sincos](https://github.com/jeremybarnes/cephes/blob/master/cmath/sincos.c) function:  and separate [sin cos](https://github.com/jeremybarnes/cephes/blob/master/cmath/sin.c) functions. Neither calls the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compute the cosine-sine pair as point on the unit circle using complex multiplication, which is equivalent to trigonometric theorems, then you automatically get both values at once.

1. ) To compute $z=e^{ix}$ compute first $z_n=e^{ix/2^n}$ using the Taylor series or polynomials with a more globally reduced error, then perform $n$ squarings $z_{k-1}=z_k^2$.
2. ) The CORDIC algorithm matches a set of angles and directions in the complex plane. These directions can, step-by-step or in the end, translated into points on the unit circle. In total, $\tan(x)$ is computed first via standard CORDIC and then the pair $(\tan(x),1)$ is scaled to unit length to give the point $(\sin(x),\cos(x))$. This obviously requires a frame procedure around it to account for the cases where $\cos x$ is negative.

However, most modern implementation work via reduction by $\pi$ or smaller fractions of $\pi$ and error-minimized polynomials on the resulting interval to get the required precision. And this procedure in the end has less complexity than the more "geometric" algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

There's always $\sin(x) = \sqrt{1 -\cos(x)^2}$ and vice versa that allows you to compute one and compute the other with a square root.

However, both glibc and musl libc actually just use two separate calls to $\sin$ and $\cos$ because the above square root has rounding errors around $x = 0$.

Modern CPUs often have a dedicated `sincos` instruction that computes both values simultaneously. So a `sincos` function could be used as an interface for that. However, for example on Intel the  CPU implementation of trigonometry functions can be quite inaccurate and can not be used  by C libraries as the default implementation.

Comment: Uhm . . . that's not what I've heard. Could you give a reference to the "CPU implementations of trig functions are not accurate . . "

Comment: @user14717 https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/

Comment: Your statement should read "Intel's CPU implementation is inaccurate", not "CPU implementations are inaccurate".